# Cognos Report Studio: how to export data table attached to chart in excel

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

Cognos Report Studio: how to export data table attached to chart in excel

I want to export a cognos report out to excel. In my report, there are two tables and two charts. When I export to excel, the charts are rendered as static images. What I want is to export the cognos report with two charts which data sources are from the two tables. Like simple charts in excel, chart data range is selected from the table.
The purpose of doing this, is for me to be able to import the excel charts to Roambi. Roambi needs a chart which data range is from a table.

Thanks a lot.
Yin.

Comment: Don't think you can do that.  A Cognos chart is always an image.  Can't you export the data from Cognos and build the chart in Roambi?

Comment: Not possible in current versions of Cognos

Comment: Why don't you use Active Reports for mobile users? -)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Cognos BI version do you have?
In Cognos 10.2 Chart is exported as Chart in Excel 2007. And you can unhide hidden list of data for chart.
But ykud is right - try Active report for mobile users.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Alexey Baturin!
I am using cognos 10.2. And I found out that there is chart data in the hidden tabs. Sorry for late reply bcos I didn't see it.
I found out that there is chart data and it's **only importing problem in Roambi**. 
I uploaded to the sharepoint as a data source for Roambi. But I can't import this file sometimes, showing the error "This file has no content. It cannot be imported". This is inconsistent.

I have found out a way to resolve:
I export the cognos report to excel.
Open the excel file, Save and Close. No need to change anything.
And upload to sharepoint.
Then I have no error and can import to Roambi.

I can’t afford any manual intervention like this, for this process.